# problem with subsubsection title

Tags: latex

Suddenly in my document all definitions of \subsubsection*{Title Text} stopped working properly.
The subsubsection number is displayed in the generated PDF and the title of the subsubsection is "*" (only the asterisk). The actual title text is displayed at the beginning of the first paragraph.

Excact code: \subsubsection*{Failure Semantics}

I'm not sure what happened. I only remember fixing some broken references...

Cleaning the output folder didn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

bja

Comment: Probably some extra spaces. Please cut and paste the relevant part into you question, exactly as it is.

Comment: No, that's not it. Double checked. This happens also with \subsection and \section.

Comment: Tough. That means that either `\subsubsection*` is undefned, or that the '*' character has a wrong 'class' (can't remember the proper name). 

I'd suggest you put your entire tex file on http://pastebin.com/ or something like that and let us have a look - make sure there is nothing secret there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, solved thx to svn diff. :)

The bad line was `\usepackage{amsmath}`! Weird.

I'll just have to use array instead of pmatrix then. :/

Thanks all.

Comment: Indeed, weird. I use amsmath a lot (always, I'd say) and I've never seen this problem. Maybe there is a conflict with some other package. And pmatrix looks way better than array, most of the time.

Comment: You are probably right. There seem to be several conflicts of amsmath and my document class (scrbook)

Comment: Why don't you list the packages you are importing?  This really, really should not be happening.

Answer (score 2):

add in the preamble

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

to include subsubsections in the table of contents you will have to add also the line

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

Answer (score 1):

check
http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/chapter3.html#sections

only add at the start of your chapter .tex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}